# Injecting spring bean from test/resources can't find class from main/java

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection

I have a spring bean defined in xml in a maven project. It uses a pojo class in src/main/java. This xml file is currently stored in src/main/resources. When built this all works fine, it gets injected in as a resource.

```
   <bean id="test" class="org.testing.framework.model.TestModel">
      values here
   </bean>
```

But I would like to move the xml file to src/test/resources but still have it reference the pojo from src/main/java, as its test data. When I move it to test it throws an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.testing.framework.model.TestModel]
```

Is it possible to move the xml spring bean file to test and use main and if so how?

Thanks

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath*:TestBeans.xml" />

</beans>
```

TestBeans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="test" class="org.testing.framework.model.TestModel">
       values....
    </bean>

    <util:map id="testMap" value-type="org.testing.framework.model.TestModel">
        <entry key="testKey" value-ref="test" />
    </util:map>

</beans>
```

Steps.java

```
package org.testing.framework.steps;

import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import net.thucydides.core.pages.Pages;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.testing.framework.model.TestModel;
import org.testing.framework.pages.XmlFilePath;

@Component
public class Steps extends AuatSteps {

    @Resource
    private XmlFilePath testXmlFilePath;

    @Resource
    private Map<String, TestModel> testMap;

    public Steps(Pages pages) {
        super(pages);
    }

    public String getXmlFilePath() {
        return testXmlFilePath.getXmlFilePath();
    }

    public Map<String, TestModel> getTestMap() {
        return testMap;
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
1069 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager  - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@233dcd27] to prepare test instance [WoWSteps$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$f625fb6]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.testing.framework.steps.Steps': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.testing.framework.model.TestModel] found for dependency [map with value type org.testing.framework.model.TestModel]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER)}
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:379)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.SpringDependencyInjector.injectDependenciesInto(SpringDependencyInjector.java:16)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepFactory.injectOtherDependenciesInto(StepFactory.java:124)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepFactory.instantiateNewStepLibraryFor(StepFactory.java:114)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepFactory.instantiateNewStepLibraryFor(StepFactory.java:100)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepFactory.getStepLibraryFor(StepFactory.java:66)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepAnnotations.instantiateAnyUnitiaializedSteps(StepAnnotations.java:50)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepAnnotations.instanciateScenarioStepFields(StepAnnotations.java:41)
    at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepAnnotations.injectScenarioStepsInto(StepAnnotations.java:23)
    at net.thucydides.jbehave.ThucydidesStepFactory.createInstanceOfType(ThucydidesStepFactory.java:80)
    at org.jbehave.core.steps.StepCandidate.getStepsInstance(StepCandidate.java:68)
    at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitDescriptionGenerator.addRegularStep(JUnitDescriptionGenerator.java:190)
    at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitDescriptionGenerator.addExistingStep(JUnitDescriptionGenerator.java:148)
    at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitDescriptionGenerator.addSteps(JUnitDescriptionGenerator.java:138)
    at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitDescriptionGenerator.addStepsToExample(JUnitDescriptionGenerator.java:127)
    at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitDescriptionGenerator.insertDescriptionForExamples(JUnitDescriptionGenerator.java:121)
    at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitDescriptionGenerator.createDescriptionFrom(JUnitDescriptionGenerator.java:55)
    at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitDescriptionGenerator.addAllScenariosToDescription(JUnitDescriptionGenerator.java:208)
    at de.codecentric.jbehave.junit.monitoring.JUnitDescriptionGenerator.createDescriptionFrom(JUnitDescriptionGenerator.java:44)
    at net.thucydides.jbehave.runners.ThucydidesReportingRunner.addStories(ThucydidesReportingRunner.java:265)
    at net.thucydides.jbehave.runners.ThucydidesReportingRunner.buildDescriptionFromStories(ThucydidesReportingRunner.java:245)
    at net.thucydides.jbehave.runners.ThucydidesReportingRunner.getDescriptions(ThucydidesReportingRunner.java:74)
    at net.thucydides.jbehave.runners.ThucydidesReportingRunner.getDescription(ThucydidesReportingRunner.java:120)
    at net.thucydides.jbehave.runners.ThucydidesReportingRunner.run(ThucydidesReportingRunner.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:234)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:166)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.testing.framework.model.TestModel] found for dependency [map with value type org.testing.framework.model.TestModel]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:824)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:749)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:438)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:550)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:303)
    ... 40 more
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.633 sec <<< FAILURE!
```

Comment: Please post the full exception stack trace.

Comment: I don't see `CannotLoadBeanClassException` in the stack trace.

Comment: My bad, I've played with it since then. I'll edit the main error.

Comment: K. Now we will need to see your context configuration and the test that requires it.

Comment: Did you copied the context files exactly or is it have some extra configuration like tx:annotation-driven for @Tranasactional...

Comment: No theres no extra configuration in the file

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around I solved the problem.

The TestBeans.xml file was placed in src/test/resources in a sub folder called applicationContext.

The following line picks the bean up from appliationContext.xml in src/main/resources completely fine

```
<import resource="classpath*:TestBeans.xml" />
```

But this bean cannot access the pojo org.testing.framework.model.TestModel

Now when i change the import to

```
<import resource="classpath*:applicationContext/TestBeans.xml" />
```

It picks up the bean fine, like the original line, but the bean can then access the pojo. I'm not clear as to why it needs the folder name as the file is picked up fine either way. It just can't access the pojo without the folder name.

Does anyone know why that would be? Thanks for looking at it anyway.